# Retrieve multiple row for certain column based from the resulting group by sql query

Tags: t-sql

I have data as per below.

```
ColumnA   ColumnB
1234      1
1234      2
1234      3
1235      2
1236      2
1237      1
1237      2
1238      1
1238      3
1238      5
```

I need output as per below, where it only shows items that has same value in 1 of the column (eg. ColumnA)

```
ColumnA   ColumnB
1234      1
1234      2
1234      3
1237      1
1237      2
1238      1
1238      3
1238      5
```

Actually I get the first table by below query, how do I modify it to get to display as per the final table?

```
select ColumnA, ColumnB
from TableX 
group by ColumnA, ColumnB
--having COUNT(ColumnA) > 1 
--having COUNT(ColumnB) > 0
order by ColumnA asc
```

UPDATE

Running below query will get below table, but it will be great if I can as per original request...

```
SELECT b.ColumnA
(
    select ColumnA, ColumnB
    from TableX 
    group by ColumnA, ColumnB
    --having COUNT(ColumnA) > 1 
    --having COUNT(ColumnB) > 0
    -- order by ColumnA asc
) b 
group by b.ColumnA
having COUNT(b.ColumnA) > 1
```

Resulting query is:

```
ColumnA 
1234      
1237      
1238
```

UPDATE

This does it! If there is any other solution, please let me know...

```
   SELECT c.*
   FROM TableX c
   WHERE c.ColumnA IN
   (
     SELECT b.ColumnA
     (
        select ColumnA, ColumnB
        from TableX 
        group by ColumnA, ColumnB
        --having COUNT(ColumnA) > 1 
        --having COUNT(ColumnB) > 0
        -- order by ColumnA asc
      ) b 
      group by b.ColumnA
      having COUNT(b.ColumnA) > 1
    )
```

Comment: If this question has an answer, it should be posted as an *answer*. If you have the answer to the question, you can post the answer yourself. Editing a question to *include* the answer is bad form. (StackOverflow operates as Question and Answer site. Having questions posted as answers, and answers posted as questions is NOT the StackOverflow way. And this question still appears (to others using StackOverflow) as *not* having an accepted answer, as if a suitable answer hasn't yet been found. (Bad form.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if my understanding is correct, you want to output rows only when columnA value is duplicated:

```
declare @tableX table
(
  ColumnA int,
  columnB int
)

insert into @tableX
values 
(1234,      1 ),
(1234,      2 ),
(1234,      3 ),
(1235,      2 ),
(1236,      2 ),
(1237,      1 ),
(1237,      2 ),
(1238,      1 ),
(1238,      3 ),
(1238,      5 )


select ColumnA, columnB
from @tableX x
where exists (select 1 from @tableX where ColumnA = x.ColumnA group by ColumnA having COUNT(*) > 1);
```